# Uniqueness of the derivative operator

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which are differentiable at all points, and let $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Let's denote by $D$ the derivative operator, i.e.

$$D:\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$$

is such that

$$D(f)=f^{\prime}$$

It's clear that $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is a real vector space and that $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of it. We also know that $D$ is linear and that it obeys the product rule

$$D(f\cdot g)=f\cdot D(g)+g\cdot D(f)$$

The question is: is $D$ the only such linear transformation, i.e., the only linear transformation that obeys product rule?

Of course, the $0$ operator and any real multiple of $D$, $\alpha\cdot D$ are trivial examples. But I'm interested in non-trivial examples.

Comment: You are looking for [derivations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)). I believe there are no other examples in this case.

Comment: are you requiring continuity? if not I think you could take different values of $\alpha$ for different subspaces. eg 1 for polynomials and 2 for non=polynomials

Comment: @MarkJoshi that's interesting. But continuity is always a good feature, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Mark you need to be a bit more subtle than that; we'd need some axiom of choice there. Also, what should "continuous" mean here?

Comment: Relative to any norm, a derivation operator over the polynomials must be unbounded

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I can't see why we'd need the axiom of choice (my guess is to ''choose'' the polynomials, but I'm not sure), and why the operator **must** be unbounded relative to **any** norm.

Comment: @Larara unless you have a basis for $\mathcal D(R)$, how do you prove that there is a linear $D$ that is non-zero on polynomials for which $D(e^x)=0$ (that is, how would you define the operator)? I'm not sure about the norm bit in retrospect

Comment: you simply define it to be one thing on polynomials and another on non-polynomials. No axiom of choice is needed for that. If we use the L2 norm for F and the H1 norm for D, differentiation is continuous.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44774/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differentiable functions are a subset of the continuous functions.  The polynomials are dense in the continuous functions on closed intervals.  (This is the Weierstrass approximation theorem.)  It is sufficient, therefore to consider what this operator does to polynomials.  It's action on non-polynomial differentiable functions or differentiable functions without compact support can be found by taking limits of polynomials.  (For instance, this limit could be of a sequence of polynomials,$(p_n(x))_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$, approximating a given differentiable function to within $1/n$ on the closed interval $[-n,n]$.  This is the same idea as is normally used for showing the simple functions are dense in the continuous functions.)

What happens when we put $1$ in for both functions?  $$
    D(1) = D(1 \cdot 1) = D(1) \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot D(1) = 2D(1) \text{.}
$$  This means $D(1) = 0$.  Since $D$ is linear, for any constant, $c$, $D(c) = 0$.

What happens to $x^2$ and $x^n$ (for $n \in \Bbb{N}$)?  \begin{align}
    D(x^2) &= D(x \cdot x) = D(x) \cdot x + x \cdot D(x) = 2 x D(x), \text{ and}  \\
    D(x^n) &= D(x \cdot x^{n-1}) = \dots = n x^{n-1} D(x) \text{.}
\end{align}  So, for any polynomial, $f$, $D(f) = f' D(x)$.  (Where we use the prime to denote "the usual derivative".  You introduced an alternative usage in your Question, but since you didn't subsequently use it, I'm stealing it to use here.)

What if we decide $D(x) = x^2$?  If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, $$
    D(f \cdot g) = D(f) \cdot g + f \cdot D(g) = f' x^2 g + f g' x^2 = (fg)' D(x) \text{.}
$$  This example is warm-up for:  what if we decide $D(x) = \phi(x)$ for any function $\phi$?  If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, $$
    D(f \cdot g) = D(f) \cdot g + f \cdot D(g) = f' \phi g + f g' \phi = (fg)' D(x) \text{.}
$$

So it appears that you can use any $\phi \in \mathcal{F}(\Bbb{R})$ as the image of $x$.  The image of $\mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R})$ will just be a "scaled and rotated" version of the normal derivative operator where the preimage of $0$ is the constants (and everything else, if you chose $\phi=0$) and the preimage of $\phi$ is $x$ and the rest of the image of $\mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R})$ falls out of this one choice.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to determine $D$ on a dense set? Why should $D$ be uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : My knee-jerk reaction is "Hahn-Banach".  But now I'm divided over whether that's actually sufficient.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : On further thought, I'm more convinced.  The LCH Stone-Weierstrass gives that the polynomials are dense in $\mathcal{C}_0(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{R})$.  This isn't $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{R})$, but I'm stumped to think of an element of $\mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R})$ that isn't in $(\text{the polynomials} \oplus \mathcal{C}_0(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{R}))$.  Maybe you can think of one that is eluding me?

Comment: again: why does the density of the polynomials matter? All we know about $D$ is that it's linear. Can't there (assuming choice) be a map $D$ that is the usual derivative on polynomials but satisfies $D(e^x)=0$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Having slept for an hour or so I might see what you're getting at.  For the usual derivative, this can't happen because the normal derivative is a densely defined, closed linear operator (on the space $\mathcal{C}^1(\Bbb{R})$).  This means that any sequence of polynomials converging to (for example) $\mathrm{e}^x$ have all their derivatives converging to the same thing.  I'm not 100% convinced that we can't break closedness.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Was your objection addressed?

Comment: I mean, I see no reason that we should make $D$ a closed operator, and I'm pretty sure we can break closedness as I described.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : If we use my construction: $Df = f' \phi$ on polynomials, then closedness forces $Df = f' \phi$ on $\mathcal{C}^1(\Bbb{R})$.  I don't reject that another class of solutions exists, but the derivation constraints are rather inflexible so I don't see how to get to it.

Comment: I just don't understand where closed mess is coming into the conversation

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Let $D$ be a closed linear operator and $(p_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ converge to, for instance, $\mathrm{e}^x$, then $(D(p_n)) \rightarrow D(\mathrm{e}^x)$.  So a closed $D$ is specified by its behaviour on the polynomials.  If you have an explicit unclosed linear $D$ that is also a derivation, I'd like to hear about it; I'm unconvinced it exists.

Comment: I'm telling you that, by the axiom of choice, it is possible to create a derivation that satisfies $D(p_n)$ is the usual derivative and $ D(e^x)=0$. You have only been looking at operators that you can explicitly construct, which is why they have all been closed.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : And I'm telling you that AC is irrelevant.  You get one choice.  Then the derivation rule removes all remaining choice.  Either that choice is finite and you get a closed operator or it isn't and you were lost at the first step.

Comment: Okay, well you're wrong.  If I find the time, I will construct a counterexample using the axiom of choice and make a post for you.  If you want to *prove* that $D$ is necessarily a closed operator (given only the premises of the question) or prove otherwise that $D$ some kind of limit for some reason, I'll be happy to take a look.